# Getting a URL from search results based on a query, and updating in a web page

Tags: command-line, google-chrome, firefox, script

Trying to find a way to do this process on a daily or even hourly basis:

1. Go to Amazon and search for "item"
2. Find a specific product in the search results (it will always have the same title)
3. Capture the link of the specific product (it changes periodically)
4. Store this link somewhere, and update a landing page the links to it (could be HTML, a Google Page, anything)

Any ideas on where to begin?

Comment: How does the link change?

Comment: It changes a qid time stamp as well as a number range that signifies where in the search results the product is located.

Comment: Looks like Selenium will help capture the link - any suggestions on a more refined way to export the link and create a redirect link that is constantly updated?

I know I could export to an HTML file that redirects, and host that somewhere. But any more efficient ways?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking into a library called Selenium. It also exists as an extension for Firefox, but I would install the lib as well to play with the code that the extension generates. Personally, I used Python.

The extension acts as a recorder for all the actions you perform in your web browser. Once you are done recording, it will attempt to generate code in the language of your choosing. In my experience you will have to tweak that code slightly to get it to work correctly, but the boiler plate and error reporting kind of stuff will be fine.

Using Selenium, you can write a script that:

1. Opens browser at amazon.com
2. Clicks search box
3. Searches for item title
4. Navigates to item page
5. Captures URL of item page
6. Exports URL to .txt or whatever else you want to do with it

Once you get the code working you can set up a task in crontab on Linux or Windows Scheduler on Windows to execute your script how ever often you like.

Here is the documentation page for Selenium for more info
http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/

Comment: I will give this a shot! Seems like something I can definitely work with.